# Code help to determine if point is in Mandelbrot set (check my solution)

Tags: c, function, ascii, mandelbrot

Here is my function that tests two points x and y if they're in the mandelbrot set or not after MAX_ITERATION 255. It should return 0 if not, 1 if it is.

```
int isMandelbrot (int x, int y) {


    int i;
    int j;
    double Re[255];
    double Im[255];
    double a;
    double b;
    double dist;
    double finaldist;
    int check;

    i=0;
    Re[0]=0;
    Im[0]=0;
    j=-1;
    a=0;
    b=0;

    while (i < MAX_ITERATION) {

        a = Re[j];
        b = Im[j];

        Re[i]=((a*a)-(b*b))+x;
        Im[i]=(2 * a * b) + y;

        i++;
        j++;
    }

    finaldist = sqrt(pow(Re[MAX_ITERATION],2)+pow(Im[MAX_ITERATION],2));

    if (dist > 2) { //not in mandelbrot
        check = 0;
    } else if (dist <= 2) { //in mandelbrot set
        check = 1;
    }

    return check;
}
```

Given that it's correct (can someone verify... or write a more efficient one?).
Here is my code to print it, however it does not work! (it keeps giving all points are in the set). What have I done wrong here?

```
int main(void) {

    double col;
    double row;

   int checkSet;

    row = -4;
    col = -1;

    while (row < 1.0 ) {
        while (col < 1.0) {
        checkSet = isMandelbrot(row, col);
            if (checkSet == 1) {
                printf("-");
            } else if (checkSet == 0) {
                printf("*");
            }
            col=col+0.5;
        }
        col=-1;
        row=row+0.5;
        printf("\n");
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to be calling your function from `main()`...

Comment: oops, copied wrong main.

Comment: Efficiency details: Do not use `pow(xxx, 2)`, the `pow` function is designed to calculate x^y for any numbers. It will do this by approximation using a complex algorithm. Use `x*x` instead. `sqrt(x) < 2` is the same as `x < 4`, but way faster. (Which was quite evident when I drew mandelbrots on my C64 twenty years ago.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some bugs in your code. For example, you do this:

```
a = Re[j];
b = Im[j];
```

But at the first iteration, `j = -1`, so you're getting the value at index -1 of the arrays. That is not what you wanted to do.

Also, why are `Re` and `Im` arrays - do you really need to keep track of all the intermediate results in the calculation?

Wikipedia contains pseudocode for [the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set), you might want to check your own code against that.

Comment: Thanks, I've read the pseudocode but I'm still having difficulties... I'm fairly new to C (or programming for that matter) can you direct me to a C version? (something I can start on)

Comment: @Carpe Diem Google for "mandelbrot in c", for example, and you'll find lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Another bug: your function takes `int` arguments, so the values of your `double` inputs will be truncated (i.e. the fractional part will be discarded).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be checking for escape inside the while loop. That is to say, if ((a*a + b*b) > 4) *at any time* then that pixel has escaped, end of story. By continuing to iterate those pixels, as well as wasting CPU cycles you the values are growing without bound and seem to be exceeding what can be represented in a `double` - the result is `NaN`, so your finaldist computation is producing garbage.

I think you would benefit from more resolution in your main. Your code as you've put it here isn't computing enough pixels to really see much of the set.

Comment: Indeed, it took quite a while to load the image. Fixed thanks for the tip!